# MVC file not loaded when submited

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have an issue file instance always null , below is the code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ExamRegisterationModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName);
            Request.Files[0].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, filename));
        }
    }
```

Any Idea how to upload the file?

And my View :

```
   <div class="input-group">
     <label for="file">Upload Receipt:</label>
     <input type="file" name="File" id="file" />
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="upload" />
   </div>
```

Comment: show your view as well

Comment: did you add form with multipart/formdata?

Comment: see this question, it will make you understand how to upload file in mvc :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125127/asp-net-mvc-4-c-sharp-httppostedfilebase-how-do-i-store-file

Answer (score 0):

add a  wrapper element.

```
<form action="/Controller/Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label for="file">Upload Receipt:</label>
        <input type="file" name="File" id="file" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works after doing the following change:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and my answer ? You didn't change the Controller name in the action attribute?