# MVC uploaded Image dose not display my table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner For the MVC ,Im Developed the My project for Image Upload Script, I want to display my uploaded image in grid, and some one need to replace the Uploaded image to other Image,My code is not working correctly, please help me, 
Image [image]
**Model**

```
public  class MainGroup
  {
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
      public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

**View -Index**

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
       <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>


            <td valign="top">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Uploaded/" + item.MainGroupID + "/" + item.Image + "")" alt="@item.MainGroupName" width="100px" height="100px" />
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MainGroupID }, new { @class = "createActor", title = "Edit Actor" })
                |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MainGroupID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**Create-Chtml**

```
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("Save", "MainGroup"))
        {

<div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="imageFile" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
    </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;"><b>Status</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(a => a.StatusId)
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6"></div> <div class="col-md-6"></div>

            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">   <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" /> </div>
        }
    </div>

}
```

**Controller**

```
 public class MainGroupController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Masters/MainGroup

        public ActionResult Save(MainGroup maingroup)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var objContext = new KnittingdbContext();
                maingroup.CreateId = 1;
                maingroup.StatusChangeDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                maingroup.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                maingroup.EditId = 1;
                maingroup.EditDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                objContext.MainGroups.Add(maingroup);

                objContext.SaveChanges();

                TempData["Success"] = "Saved Sucessfully";

                return RedirectToAction("MainGroupIndex", new { A = "New" });
            }





            else
            {
                return PartialView("_MainGroupCreate", maingroup);
            }


        }
```

Comment: have you checked is path to image rendered right way in browser?

Comment: Sir, yeah.I think my controller not a correctly work

Comment: You can define file as a HttpFileBase property to hold file then in post method(Save)  move file to   "~/Content/Uploaded/". Then try. Also you can check directory manually if image file available

Comment: sir @unique can you explain it? example code

Comment: @Cola check edited comment

Comment: @Cola refer this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125127/asp-net-mvc-4-c-sharp-httppostedfilebase-how-do-i-store-file and more details http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files

Comment: Sir thanks for the help, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define file as a HttpFileBase property to hold file then in post method(Save) move file to "~/Content/Uploaded/". Then try. Also you can check directory manually if image file available

```
public  class MainGroup
{
  [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
  public string Image { get; set; }

  public HttpFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }

 }
```

public class MainGroupController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Masters/MainGroup

```
    public ActionResult Save(MainGroup maingroup)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // You can add other logic also
            if(maingroup.ImageFile!= null && maingroup.ImageFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
               string filePath = "~/Content/Uploaded/";
               string imageUrl = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, maingroup.ImageFile.File.FileName);
               var objContext = new KnittingdbContext();
               maingroup.CreateId = 1;
               maingroup.Image = imageUrl;
               maingroup.ImageFile.File.SaveAs(imageUrl));
               maingroup.StatusChangeDate = System.DateTime.Now;
               maingroup.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
               maingroup.EditId = 1;
               maingroup.EditDate = System.DateTime.Now;
               objContext.MainGroups.Add(maingroup);
               objContext.SaveChanges();
              TempData["Success"] = "Saved Sucessfully";


             }      

            return RedirectToAction("MainGroupIndex", new { A = "New" });
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_MainGroupCreate", maingroup);
        }


    }
```